# Create an object with changing members

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following class:

```
class Type1
{
    var1:string;
    var3:string;
}

var t1 = new Type1();
t1.var1 = "Hello";
```

The problem is that sometimes this class will have instead of var1 an object called var2:

```
class Type1
{
    var2:string;
    var3:string;
}
var t1 = new Type1();
t1.var2 = "World";
```

I would also like to use it as so:

```
var t1:Type1 = {var1:"Hello",var3:"SUCCESS"};
```

or

```
var t1:Type1 = {var2:"Hello",var3:"SUCCESS"};
```

and I also need to do this:

```
var t3 = new Type1();
```

the names var1 and var 2 are mandatory as I get them from outside.
how can I create this type of object(without casting to any)?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not actually clear you need a class, can you not just work with an interface. This code works for me:

```
interface IType1 {
    var1?: string;
    var2?: string;
    var3: string;
}

var t1: IType1 = { var1: "Hello", var3: "SUCCESS" };
var t1: IType1 = { var2: "Hello", var3: "SUCCESS" };
```

Comment: I have tried this before posting the question. I get the following error: TS1112 TypeScript A class member cannot be declared optional.

Comment: Sorry yes, this would be in the interface IType1. In the Type1 implementation class you can omit the ?, it will work without.

Comment: Just tried this. the problem is that it doesn't work with this part of my question: var t1:Type1 = {var1:"Hello"};

Comment: Change it to be of type IType1, not Type1

Comment: Updated the question: added var3. BTW, Thanks for the help.

Comment: Np, updated my answer again, do you need a class or can you just use an interface?

Comment: I also need classes. If this is not possible do you know why?

Comment: Optional members are not supported in class definitions only interfaces. You can create a class with the members you want, but not construct it from Json.

Comment: although this is not the answer I hoped to find I guess this is the answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want - you wish to create an object with a string named var1 or var2.
I would write it like this:

```
function Type1(name, data) {
  this[name] = data;
}

var t1 = new Type1("var1", "Hello");    // {var1: "hello"}
var t2 = new Type1("var2", "Hello 2");  // {var2: "Hello 2"}
```

Comment: Your answer might work but I am looking for a more strongly typed approach. With your approach I don't have intellisense and no error checking. That is why I don't want to make casting to 'any'.

Comment: My answer is pure JavaScript. I guess you are looking for a TypeScript solution (which I have no knowledge of).

Answer (score 0):

Since var1 and var2 are coming from outside, maybe you should declare them outside of your class

```
declare var var1:string;
declare var var2:string;
```

and then do some check in the class about which one you are going to use.

Comment: But then I will loose intellisense and type safety. no?

Comment: You can still declare the type of them, I' m not sure for intellisense